# Latex workshop VSCode does not compile

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, latex, bibtex

I am using MacBook and Visual Studio Code to write latex papers. Today in the middle of work VScode stopped to compile all the files giving errors:
[image: Errors in log]

PDF comes but without bibliography.

Latex workshop v8.26 the latest.

Any ideas what could happened and how to fix that?

Files compile on overleaf so I assume code is correctly written.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Need to erase cache files.

In terminal:

```
rm -rf `biber --cache`
```